# Can a try-catch block be interpreted as a monad when coupled with a Either-like monad?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, try-catch, monads

[*Functional Programming in C++*](https://livebook.manning.com/book/functional-programming-in-c-plus-plus/about-this-book/) shows, in section 10.5.2, the `expected<T,E>` monad which is the same as Haskell's `Either`.

So far so good.

Then, in section 10.5.3, it claims to show *The Try monad*, or at least this is the title of the section.

Of this "monad", only a function is shown, instead of `mbind`, and it is called `mtry`, and it takes in input not a *value* to be wrapped in the "try monad", but a fuction which, when run, can return a value or throw an exception, each of which is then appropriately wrapped in the `expected` monad.

So I was wandering if I'm misunderstanding the point of the author which is clear to most readers but me, or that title is really misleading.

Comment: `Try` seems to just defer the effect (unwind the call stack) by wrapping it in a function.It's like if you have a mutable data type and just defer the mutation: Such computations can still be harmful when you run them.

Answer (score 1):

The `mtry` function in your book is basically a useful way to construct an `expected` monad with one side's type always being an exception.

Other languages like Scala have a separate `Try[A]` type where all the monady stuff is duplicated instead of constructing an `Either`, but there are some methods specifically tailored to be handy because you know you are working with an exception, like if you throw an exception in its `map` it will recapture it in the `Try` instead of propagating it. It's a great way to wrap imperative-style exception code and convert thrown exceptions to values.

I suppose if you knew about Scala's `Try`, that section of the book would make a lot more sense. The author isn't really attempting to show you how to make an entire standalone `Try`, just showing how the concept would map back to the previous sections. He is basically omitting the `mbind` because it wouldn't be any different than `expected`.